# Convert REG_BINARY value (64 bit Hex Value - Little Endian) to date and time

Tags: bash, shell, computer-forensics

I would like to convert a Windows NT Shutdown Time to Date and Time:

```
88 33 9d cb 38 36 d0 01 --> 88339dcb3836d001 --> 22.01.2015 11:44:35 (UTC)
```

The input data is this 64 bit hex value (8 bytes). You find this value in your windows registry under `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows --> Shutdown Time`. This value contains time and date of last shutdown. The value is of type `FILETIME` - A 64-bit time value (Hex Value, Little Endian) representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight UTC, 1 Jan 1601.

Is this possible via shell (bash)? I would like to implement it in a shell script.

Comment: Do you know how the calculation works? If so, this can easily be done using shell tools. What is the format of your input data? Please [edit] your question to provide more details.

Comment: Like I said, [edit] your question rather than using the comments to add more detail. How should the shell script access this value? Is it in a text file, or a shell variable, or what?

Comment: That's not my question! I have this value already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the question, a Windows NT shutdown time is a count of 100ns intervals from 1st January 1601. The only catch is that the timestamp is encoded as little-endian. Decoding the timestamp and adding it to the epoch is a bit tricky in pure Bash, but becomes rather easy if you can spare a Python installation.

Here is a script doing the conversion:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from __future__ import division
import struct
import sys
from binascii import unhexlify
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

nt_timestamp = struct.unpack("<Q", unhexlify(sys.argv[1]))[0]
epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
nt_datetime = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=nt_timestamp / 10)

print(nt_datetime.strftime("%c"))
```

It accepts the 64bit value as an argument and prints the locale representation of the date encoded:

```
$ ./nttime.py 88339dcb3836d001
Thu Jan 22 11:44:35 2015
```

If you need another format, then edit the last line using the standard `strftime()` format specifiers.

Comment: I changed /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/local/bin/python3 on my mac. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To share more knowledge :-)

```
$regKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path
Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
$shutDown = $regKey.ShutdownTime
$Int64Value = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($shutDown, 0)
$date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Int64Value)

$date
```

Got this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202411/read-registery-value-and-convert-to-date)