# Read Registery value and convert to date

Tags: powershell, datetime, registry

I am trying to find the uptime of windows machine (last shutdown time) using following code:

```
$computernames = gc LegAservers.txt
foreach ($computername in $computernames) {
  $baseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$computername)
  $sKey = "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows"
  $key = $baseKey.OpenSubKey($sKey)
  $kvalue = $key.GetValue("ShutdownTime")
  $kvalue
  "------------------------------------------"
  $baseKey.Close()
}
```

Output is:

```
13
152
105
75
132
217
208
1
------------------------------------------
```

I am unable to covert this `$kvalue` in `DateTime` format using:

```
[DateTime]::FromFileTime($kvalue)
```

Please suggest proper way to convert `$kvalue` in date and time format so that it can be understood by user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$regKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
$shutDown = $regKey.ShutdownTime
$Int64Value = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($shutDown, 0)
$date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Int64Value)

$date
```

Comment: Sorry for digging up an old thread. I'm trying to convert the key "DateLastConnected" @ HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{GUID} but I'm getting inaccurate results. For eg: e4,07,07,00,01,00,1b,00,11,00,16,00,06,00,3b,00 is being converted to 31 January 1625 07:51:06

Answer (score 4):

How does the ShutdownTime help you to determine the uptime? I would suggest you to use the win32_operationsystem CimInstance to determine it:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select lastbootuptime
```

Comment: Funny: I have a 23 seconds difference between the time returned by your WMI query and the time retrieved from registry.

Comment: Agreed but I am not able to execute same command on remote servers. I guess firewall restrictions. 

Since its prod server thus i can calculate uptime as current time - shutdown time. I accept it will not be accurate but it will do the thing for me meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar approach to @David Brabant, but with one less line:

```
$shutDown = Get-ItemPropertyValue "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows" -Name ShutdownTime
$Int64Value = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($shutDown, 0)
$date = [datetime]::FromFileTime($Int64Value)

$date
```

Cmdlet **Get-ItemPropertyValue** is only compatible with Powershell version 5.

Comment: f4d0 - since we are shortening things. ;-}   # No variables - One line
[datetime]::FromFileTime($([System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($(Get-ItemPropertyValue "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows" -Name ShutdownTime), 0)))

# Or no variables - One line using natual line PowerShell breaks
[datetime]::
FromFileTime($([System.BitConverter]::
ToInt64($(Get-ItemPropertyValue "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows" -Name ShutdownTime), 0)))

Answer (score 0):

Not all registry entries have a direct conversion to DateTime. Some arrays are compound.

Compressed function

```
function GetRegDate ($path, $key){
    function GVl ($ar){
        return [uint32]('0x'+(($ar|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''))
    }
    $ar=Get-ItemPropertyValue $path $key
    [array]::reverse($ar)
    $time = New-Object DateTime (GVl $ar[14..15]),(GVl $ar[12..13]),(GVl $ar[8..9]),(GVl $ar[6..7]),(GVl $ar[4..5]),(GVl $ar[2..3]),(GVl $ar[0..1])
    return $time
}
$path='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{6CB1FEAE-02B2-4922-8D81-331219215E21}'
$key='DateLastConnected'
$DateLastConnected=GetRegDate $path $key
Get-Date $DateLastConnected -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
```

Original function

```
# http://cfed-ttf.blogspot.com/2009/08/decoding-datecreated-and.html
$path='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{6CB1FEAE-02B2-4922-8D81-331219215E21}'
$key='DateLastConnected'
$dateArr=Get-ItemPropertyValue $path $key
[array]::reverse($dateArr)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[0..1]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$mSeconds = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[2..3]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Seconds = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[4..5]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$minutes = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[6..7]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$hour = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[8..9]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$date = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[10..11]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Weekday =[uint32]$chank
$WeekdayLong = (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetDayName([uint32]$Weekday)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[12..13]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Month = [uint32]$chank
$LongMonth = (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName([uint32]$Month)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[14..15]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Year = [uint32]$chank

$time = New-Object DateTime $Year, $Month, $date, $hour, $minutes, $Seconds, $mSeconds
Get-Date $time -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are driven by simple curiosity

you can use this

```
$encoded='2F 49 94 B0 D9 CE D6 01'
$encoded=$encoded.Split(' ')
[array]::reverse($encoded)
$encoded=$encoded -join ''
$asDecimal = [System.Convert]::ToInt64($encoded, 16)
$date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($asDecimal)
$date
```

or

```
function GetRegDate ($ar){
    function GVl ($ar){
        return [uint32]('0x'+($ar[0]+$ar[1]))
    }
    $ar=$ar.Split(' ') 
    [array]::reverse($ar)
    $time = New-Object DateTime (GVl $ar[14..15]),(GVl $ar[12..13]),(GVl $ar[8..9]),(GVl $ar[6..7]),(GVl $ar[4..5]),(GVl $ar[2..3]),(GVl $ar[0..1])
    return $time
}
$chanked='E4 07 0C 00 00 00 14 00 0A 00 07 00 22 00 E5 00'
$date=GetRegDate $chanked
$date=Get-Date $date
$date
```

Answer (score 0):

So simplify and rewrite everything above...

```
function GetRegDate ($path, $key){
    function DW2i($ar){return $ar[1]*256+$ar[0]}
    $ar=gpv $path $key
    $time = New-Object DateTime (DW2i $ar[0..1]),(DW2i $ar[2..3]),(DW2i $ar[6..7]),(DW2i $ar[8..9]),(DW2i $ar[10..11]),(DW2i $ar[12..13]),(DW2i $ar[14..15])
    return $time
}
```

or you might just take a step back and looking just see that the registry entry is formatted and get at this same better cleaner code without the reverse or the -joins etc...

```
'E4 07 0C 00 00 00 14 00 0A 00 07 00 22 00 E5 00'
' 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15'
 \yr / \mth/       \day/ \hh / \mm / \ss / \ms /
```

so ...

```
function getRegDate($path,$key) {
  function DW2i($dw){return $dw[1]*256+$dw[0]}
  $ar=gpv $path $key
 #return get-date -Y (DW2i $ar[0..1]) -Mon (DW2i $ar[2..3]) -Day (DW2i $ar[6..7]) -h (DW2i $ar[8..9]) -min (DW2i $ar[10..11]) -sec (DW2i $ar[12..13]) -milli (DW2i $ar[14..15])
  return new-object datetime (DW2i $ar[0..1]), (DW2i $ar[2..3]), (DW2i $ar[6..7]), (DW2i $ar[8..9]), (DW2i $ar[10..11]), (DW2i $ar[12..13]), (DW2i $ar[14..15])
}
```

using `new-object datetime` same speed as `get-date`... perhaps a second or two if done in a 1..9999 for-loop.

I just wanted a quick one off and only cared about the date so I bypassed the function and just used this

```
(gci 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\')|gp|select @{N='dateUsed';E={('{1}-{2:d2}-{3:d2}' -f ($d=$_.DateLastConnected),($d[0]+$d[1]*256),$d[2],$d[6])}},@{N='dateMade';E={('{1}-{2:d2}-{3:d2}' -f ($d=$_.DateCreated),($d[0]+$d[1]*256),$d[2],$d[6])}},@{N='ProfType';E={(('Public','Private','Domain')[$_.Category])}},NameType, PSChildName, ProfileName | sort dateUsed -d | ft -auto
```