# Difficulties converting Hex String to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, datetime

I'm trying to convert some hex strings that were provided via a different application to the correct DateTime value, however no matter what I try, the value is always wrong.  The hex strings came from several systems' ShutdownTime registry key converted by a different application to hex when read.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
$shutdownkey = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\' -Name ShutdownTime

$bitconverted = [DateTime]::FromFileTime([System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($shutdownkey.ShutdownTime, 0))

$hextime = "C11E6DF46024D101"

$test = [DateTime]::FromFileTime([Convert]::ToInt64($hextime, 16))
```

So the first two lines work normally when I use, for example, my own ShutdownTime key, but when I use the last two or any of the following:

C9520B970A69D101

0A44A6EA3300D101

C11E6DF46024D101

It either fails or gives me an impossible timestamp.  However, if I use a tool like [DCode](http://www.digital-detective.net/digital-forensic-software/free-tools/), it successfully converts it with Decode Format of "Windows: 64 bit Hex Value - Little Endian".  From what I am reading in several places, .NET uses little endian, so this shouldn't be an issue with encoding, but I suspect that it is.

Can anyone help me figure out how to solve this conversion issue?  It's bugging me why I can't figure this out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202411/read-registery-value-and-convert-to-date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endianness is backward. The times should be reversed. For example:

```
C9520B970A69D101 should be 01D1690A970B52C9 
[DateTime]::FromFileTime(0x01D1690A970B52C9) gives (Tuesday, February 16, 2016 4:37:17 PM)
```

Comment: and how would you flip this hex number in powershell? is there a convert from/to encoding?

Comment: Generally additional questions should be posted as a new question. That said, you could use the [System.BitConverter] class to convert a `Uint64` to an array of bytes, reverse the array (`[array]::reverse`), and then convert the reversed array back to `Uint64`.

Comment: That's exactly the info I was looking for.  And Anthony's response was the same followup I would have made, so thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Sometime an Hex String date can be a Unix TimeStamp, UTC timestamp etc..
Here are some quick converts to try.

```
$hexValue =0x61D75331
[datetimeoffset]::FromUnixTimeSeconds([Convert]::ToInt64($hexValue)).datetime
[datetime]::FromFileTime([Convert]::ToInt64($hexValue))
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc([Convert]::ToInt64($hexValue))
[datetime]::FromBinary([Convert]::ToInt64($hexValue))
```

Gives

```
January 6, 2022 20:38:09 #was what I needed
December 31, 1600 19:02:44
January 1, 1601 00:02:44
January 1, 0001 00:02:44
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Read Registery value and convert to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202411/read-registery-value-and-convert-to-date)
David Brabant comment

```
$regKey = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
$shutDown = $regKey.ShutdownTime
$Int64Value = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt64($shutDown, 0)
$date = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Int64Value)

$date
```

And my extention

Not all registry entries have a direct conversion to DateTime. Some arrays are compound.

Compressed function

```
function GetRegDate ($path, $key){
    function GVl ($ar){
        return [uint32]('0x'+(($ar|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join ''))
    }
    $ar=Get-ItemPropertyValue $path $key
    [array]::reverse($ar)
    $time = New-Object DateTime (GVl $ar[14..15]),(GVl $ar[12..13]),(GVl $ar[8..9]),(GVl $ar[6..7]),(GVl $ar[4..5]),(GVl $ar[2..3]),(GVl $ar[0..1])
    return $time
}
$path='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{6CB1FEAE-02B2-4922-8D81-331219215E21}'
$key='DateLastConnected'
$DateLastConnected=GetRegDate $path $key
Get-Date $DateLastConnected -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
```

Original function

```
# http://cfed-ttf.blogspot.com/2009/08/decoding-datecreated-and.html
$path='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{6CB1FEAE-02B2-4922-8D81-331219215E21}'
$key='DateLastConnected'
$dateArr=Get-ItemPropertyValue $path $key
[array]::reverse($dateArr)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[0..1]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$mSeconds = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[2..3]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Seconds = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[4..5]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$minutes = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[6..7]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$hour = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[8..9]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$date = [uint32]$chank

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[10..11]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Weekday =[uint32]$chank
$WeekdayLong = (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetDayName([uint32]$Weekday)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[12..13]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Month = [uint32]$chank
$LongMonth = (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName([uint32]$Month)

$chank = '0x'+(($dateArr[14..15]|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')
$Year = [uint32]$chank

$time = New-Object DateTime $Year, $Month, $date, $hour, $minutes, $Seconds, $mSeconds
Get-Date $time -Format "ddd, dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff"
```